# jQuery - Attach a delete button to autoappend script?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, append

**REVISED CODE AT THE END**

I'm very new to jquery, and even though I love it, there's a lot I still need to learn... The code below will append a new row if the user clicks in the one of the existing cells in a row.  That part works fine.  I'm trying to figure out how to also have a [-] button at the end of each row that a user can click on to remove that row in case they make a mistake?  Is that even possible?

**Here's the jquery**

```
$( function(){
        $("#knotes > tbody > tr > td > input").bind('focus', function(){
            var row = $(this).closest("tr").get(0);
            if( row.className.indexOf("clicked")==-1 )
            {       
                    var rowCopy=$(row).clone(true);
                    $(row).closest("tbody").append(rowCopy);
                    row.className+="clicked";
                    var newInput=$("input",rowCopy).get(0);
                    newInput.id="newId";
                    $(newInput).bind('focus',attachAutoCompleteEmployeeValues);
            }
        });
});
```

**Here's the markup**

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="knotes">
<thead bgcolor="#f7f9c9">
    <td align="center"><label for="name">Name</label></td>
    <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap"><label for="kot">OT </label></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap"><label for="kdt">DT </label></td>

    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center"><label for="kbreak">Bk?</label></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center"><label for="kshift">Shift</label></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</thead>

<tr>
    <td align="center" class="kac" id="test"><input type="text" id="kemployee" name="klabor[kemployee][]" /></td>

    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="klabor[kot][]"  /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="klabor[kdt][]"  /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="klabor[kbreak][]"  /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="klabor[kshift][]"  /></td>

</tr>
</table>
```

**HERE IS THE REVISED CODE**
The revised jQuery

```
$( function(){
        $("#knotes > tbody > tr > td > input").bind('focus', function(){
            var row = $(this).closest("tr").get(0);
            if( row.className.indexOf("clicked")==-1 )
            {       
                    var rowCopy=$(row).clone(true);
                    $(row).closest("tbody").append(rowCopy);
                    row.className+="clicked";
                    var newInput=$("input",rowCopy).get(0);
                    newInput.id="newId";
                    $(newInput).bind('focus',attachAutoCompleteEmployeeValues);
                    $('minus').live(function(){$(this).closest('tr').remove();});
            }
        });
});
```

The revised markup

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="knotes">
<thead bgcolor="#f7f9c9">
    <td align="center"><label for="name">Name</label></td>
    <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap"><label for="kot">OT </label></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap"><label for="kdt">DT </label></td>

    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center"><label for="kbreak">Bk?</label></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center"><label for="kshift">Shift</label></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</thead>

<tr>
    <td align="center" class="kac" id="test"><input type="text" id="kemployee" name="klabor[kemployee][]"  /></td>

    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="klabor[kot][]" value=""  /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="klabor[kdt][]" value=""  /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="klabor[kbreak][]" value=""  /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="klabor[kshift][]" value="" /></td><td class="minus"><img src="/images/minus.png" /></td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `live` method.

```
$(".removeMe").live('click',function(){ 
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

Now when ever you add or clone html code like `<a class='removeMe'>(-) Remove</a>` jQuery will set an onclick event for it.

Edit:

```
$( function(){

        $('.minus').live(function(){$(this).closest('tr').remove();});

        $("#knotes > tbody > tr > td > input").bind('focus', function(){
            var row = $(this).closest("tr").get(0);
            if( row.className.indexOf("clicked")==-1 )
            {       
                    var rowCopy=$(row).clone(true);
                    $(row).closest("tbody").append(rowCopy);
                    row.className+="clicked";
                    var newInput=$("input",rowCopy).get(0);
                    $(newInput).bind('focus',attachAutoCompleteEmployeeValues);
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: I really appreciate the clarification, but when I do this (exactly as it's written), I get this:

F is undefined
[Break on this error] (function(){var R=/((?:\\((?:\\([^()]+\\)|[...(J,typeof K==="string"?K:K+"px")}})})();

Comment: I guess attachAutoCompleteEmployeeValues is null

Answer (score 1):

yes:

```
$('button').live(function(){$(this).closest('tr').remove();});
```

where 'button' is a selector representing your [-] button.

Also, a few changes can be made to optimise your code (and make it more cross-browser compatible):

```
if( row.className.indexOf("clicked")==-1 )
row.className+="clicked";
newInput.id="newId";
```

should become:

```
if (row.hasClass('clicked'))
row.addClass('clicked');
newInput.attr('id','newId');
```

Comment: I use it all the time! Extremely useful

Comment: I don't think I'm implementing this the right way or something, because I'm getting an error "exprValue is undefined"... I'll revised my original post so that you can see the revised markup and code... Thanks for the help, by the way... Hope you can help me a little more...

Comment: And $("minus") should be $(".minus")